# Reusable JS ajax pattern (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, design-patterns

I'd like to know if there is a better approach to creating re-usable ajax object for jquery.

This is my un-tested code.

```
var sender = {
    function ajax(url, type, dataType,  callback) {
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: type,
            dataType: dataType,
            beforeSend: function() {
                onStartAjax();
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                callback.failure(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown);
            },
            success: function(data, textStatus) {
                callback.success(data, textStatus);
            },
            complete: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) {
                onEndAjax();
            }
        });
    },
    function onStartAjax() {
        // show loader
    },
    function onEndAjax() {
        // hide loader
    }  
};


<script type="text/javascript">
    var callback = {
        success: function(data, textStatus) {
            $('#content').html(data);
        },
        failure: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('Error making AJAX call: ' + XMLHttpRequest.statusText + ' (' + XMLHttpRequest.status + ')');
        }
    }

    sender.ajax(url, type, dataType, callback);

</script>
```

Comment: you might consider returning the promise itself in your sender.ajax (`return $.ajax({...})`) so that you can attach other callbacks from the client. Of course if you rather prefer to completely hide jquery's ajax from the other code, you should not do that.

Answer (score 4):

You can set the basic options that you always have the same separately.

for instance if you always use the same thing here:

```
    type: type, 
    dataType: dataType,
```

for those types, you can set them separately.

Here is how you do that type of thing:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  type: "POST",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  data: "{}"
});
```

NOW those are set and you can simplify your individual ajax calls.

EDIT:

NOTE: Setting parameters to $.ajax override these defaults. Thus presetting “data” to an empty JSON string is safe and desired. This way, any $.ajax call that does specify a data parameter will function as expected, since the default will not be used.  This helps avoid issues that can be difficult to find on a deployed site.

Comment: That's a good tip. However, I am more interested in a design pattern that's better than what I have.

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I did:

```
var ajaxclient = (function (window) {

    function _do(type, url)
    {
        return $.ajax({
            url:url,
            type:type,
            dataType:'json',
            beforeSend: _onStartAjax                
        }).always(_onEndAjax);
    }

    function _onStartAjax()
    {
        console.log("starting ajax call");
    }

    function _onEndAjax()
    {
        console.log("finished ajax call");
    }

    return {
        do:_do
    }
}(this));
```

Example usage:

```
ajaxclient.do("get","http://...").done(function(data) {console.log(data);})
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably go the whole hog and have an Ajax Object create.

```
var ajax = new MySuperAjax(url, data);
ajax.onComplete = function(){}
```

or similar. You seem to have a halfway between a function which has some defaults it extends with those you apss in and an object for it.